# Combining multiple select queries issue

Tags: mysql, select, union

MySql query question:

Being a newbie in sql I've got the following question.
I am having to trouble to combine 4 queries into one for use in reporting software. The code is working, but the outcome is not how I desire.

Tried to use the UNION statement, this displays the counts but all sorted under 1 'count(*)' field.

I would like to have 4 fields as stated into each query (total alarms, total acknowledged, total acknowledged within 15min, total acknowledged after 15 min)

This is my code so far:

```
select
  count(*) 'Total alarms'
 FROM  alarminfo
 where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0'))

union 

select
 count(ack_time) 'Total Acknowledged'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0')

 )

union 

select
   count(*) 'Total acknowledged within 15min'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0') AND
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)<60*15))

union 

select
   count(*) 'Total acknowledged after 15min'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0') AND
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15))
```

Anyone an idea how to sort each count under a separate field ?

Comment: If you want to get the results in one record, use @P.Salmon 's answer, if you want them in multiple records, you could use mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need conditional aggregation. for example

```
select
  count(*) 'Total alarms',
  sum(case when ack_time is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'total acknowledged',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)<60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged within 15min',
  sum(case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total acknowledged after 15min'
 FROM  alarminfo
 where
 alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is about what I am after for.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the same column name in all union queries.

Second, if you want all to be the same name, then you should use "UNION ALL" in case results has duplicate records.

In you case you can do this:

```
select
  count(*) AS 'count', 'Total alarms' As 'label' 
 FROM  alarminfo
 where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0'))

union 

select
 count(ack_time) AS 'count', 'Total Acknowledged' As 'label'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0')

 )

union 

select
   count(*) AS 'count', 'Total acknowledged within 15min' AS 'label'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0') AND
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)<60*15))

union 

select
   count(*) AS 'count',  'Total acknowledged after 15min' AS 'label'
 FROM  alarminfo
  where
 ((alarminfo.set_time>='2017-09-01 00:00:00.0' AND alarminfo.set_time<'2017-09-15 23:59:59.0') AND
    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,alarminfo.set_time ,alarminfo.ack_time)>60*15))
```

Comment: Thanks Lamar, your answer gives me some more insight in this.